# javascript merge regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

When `/^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/` **means** require all src files except `./main.js`,
`/^\.\/(?!style.*)/` **means** require all src files except `./style/*`

Then I use `/^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$) | ^\.\/(?!style.*)/` want to require all src files except `./main.js` and `./style/*` but not work

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just merge the lookaheads, no need to repeat the consuming pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to repeat consuming patterns, just put the conditions inside the negative lookahead:

```
/^\.\/(?!style|main(\.js)?$)/
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dmOjjA/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\.\/` - a `./` substring
- `(?!style|main(\.js)?$)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if immediately to the right of the current location, there is:

  - `style` - a literal `style` substring
  - `main(\.js)?$` - `main` or `main.js` substrings at the end of the string (`$`)

However, you note that `style` should be followed with `/` in the requirement, but your regex does not have that check. You may append `(\/|$)` after `style` to enforce that check (a `/` or end of string should appear right after `style`):

```
/^\.\/(?!style(\/|$)|main(\.js)?$)/
```

With this regex, [`./style-main.js` will be matched](https://regex101.com/r/ycIZi8/1).